# How to set tarball url of node-gyp via environment variable

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I want to use custom node tarball to build node modules via node-gyp, is there any way to set it via environment variable or some config files for node-gyp or npm?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ok, I figure it out now, node-gyp currently doesn't support to set tarball url, but we can set disturl via environment variable or config files.

in **~/.npmrc**, we can add `disturl=...` to set disturl.
also we can set `npm_config_disturl` as a environment variable and it will be treated as a npm config variable.

with the `disturl`, `node-gyp` will get tarball url

Comment: sorry, is this still applicable? I have no internet access directly on the machine and I need to set this - I also don't understand the steps, could you kindly elaborate on the steps?